# Can't scroll ListView when there are too many entries

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with ArrayAdapter and when i have too many entries (1000+), it can't be scrolled.

Gives me this error when i try to scroll:

Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Maybe try a RecyclerView. It can handle more items?.

Comment: @Insignificant Person Are you using the `Viewholder` patter???

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for this.